# plotting a marginal map overlaid to a density/count plot

Tags: r, maps, overlay, density-plot

I have some longitude position data and I want to show its variation over time for each of the several different individuals of study. I also want to do a marginal tile-like density plot on top of it but I need it to show where this density is on a map so I need a geographical map overlaid on top of it.

My data looks something like this:

```
SO <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 365), 3),
             julian = rep(seq(1,365,1),3),          
             ind = c(rep(1,365), rep(2,365), rep(3,365)),
             longitude = c(rnorm(365, mean = 90, sd =5), rnorm(365, mean = 85, sd =2), rnorm(365, mean = 92, sd =3)))
```

So far I have managed to plot the longitudes fitted with smoothed lines and flip coordinates to leave longitude in the x-axis. My code currently looks like this:

```
ggplot(SO, aes(x = julian, y = longitude)) +
          geom_point(aes(color=factor(ind)), size = 0.1) +
          stat_smooth(aes(group= factor(ind)), se = FALSE)+
          stat_smooth(aes(color=factor(ind))) +
          coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse()
```

However I have got stuck with plotting the tile density and overlaying a map to it. The result should look like this.

[image: Desired result]

If you can just come up with how to overlay the map to the density plot that would already be of great help. Thank you very much.

Comment: The coordinates of the map (lat x long)  do not match the coordinates of the density plot (time x long). There would seem to be a dimensional analysis incompatibility.

Comment: For the example image? I made it in Paint to look like what I want to get but it is not a real thing.

Comment: I suspect I'm misinterpreting you request. You don't want to "overlay"  them but rather have the registration of the longitude axes of the stacked graphics match up in the same document?

Comment: Sorry if my description has been confusing. Firstly I don´t know haow to overlay a map to a tile density plot and secondly I don´t know how to make this match the time x long plot.